# Database version control for Java SE applicataion

Tags: java, mysql, git, version-control

I'm doing a desktop Application using Java SE and MYSQL as Database. I'm adding new features which may alter database tables and views. I need to know best way to commit database change to my source control. My clients are running different versions of my product. So this must help me when upgrading new version of the application.

What are the Database version control systems available?

What are the database solution suits desktop application development scenario?

Comment: If you are doing your changes manually (via Workbench or similar) you will need to script them and commit this SQL code to your repository.

Comment: Yeap I'm using mysql workbench or mysql query browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools designed for applying DB changes incrementally to different database instances (Client A & Client B; Dev & Test & Production; etc). These tools will still require from you to put these files under version control (so they will not do that for you), but many other aspects of the job will be handled by them. I would suggest taking a look at these two:

- [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/)
- [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)

And [this](http://techieindescribable.blogspot.hu/2013/08/comparison-between-flyway-and-liquibase.html) is a short comparison of them.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple google results that might point you in the right direction.

http://ben.kulbertis.org/2011/10/synchronizing-a-mysql-database-with-git-and-git-hooks/

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/241109/is-backing-up-a-mysql-database-in-git-a-good-idea

It looks like the basic premise is to use hooks to connect into your MySQL Database, then commit as you would do regularly.

Comment: I currently do is something like this i take to backups from the two version and you a diff tool to check the difference.this is bit of time consuming thing.